# Getting table headings when creating a table with two variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have created a table, and I want the variables that run through to create it, as the headings in their respective place.

So when my table is created by variable `a` and `b`, each going  from 1 to 10 with step 1, I would like to get the table in a form that horizontal I have `a` and vertical I have `b`, and the values put in in their correct place.

Is there a way to achive that?

Answer (score 1):

```
TableForm[Table[f[a, b], {a, 10}, {b, 10}], 
          TableHeadings -> {Range[10], Range[10]}, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

That's just the simplest 10-by-10 example, which is what the original question asked. Here's something close to what the first comment below asks for:

```
TableForm[Table[f[a, b], {a, 3, 30, 3}, {b, 60, 100, 10}],
          TableHeadings -> {Range[3, 30, 3], Range[60, 100, 10]}, TableSpacing->{1, 1}]
```

[image]

The form inside the table is just to indicate that whatever actual function you might use. For example:

```
f[x_, y_] := N[Sin[x] Log[y]]
TableForm[Table[f[a, b], {a, 3, 30, 3}, {b, 60, 100, 10}], 
          TableHeadings -> {Range[3, 30, 3], Range[60, 100, 10]}, 
          TableSpacing -> {1, 1}, TableAlignments -> "."]
```

[image]

If this is not the sort of display you're trying to obtain, then you'll have to explain in greater detail, and with a specific example of the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand :(  For example my A goes from 3 to 30 in steps of 3 and my b goes from 60 to 100 or something. I dont want to get the numbers displayed 1,2,3,4, i just want the values that goes into the calculation at that spot to be the headings.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table or matrix using the `Table` command, you want the variable that goes with the rows to come first, and the variable for the columns to come second.

```
mytable = Table[f[a, b], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}];
```

Then to view the results in a visually pleasing manner, use `TableForm`

```
mytable // TableForm
```

[image]